# Triangle/Geometry question

Tags: triangles

How do I solve this triangle question?

In the figure below $\Delta OAB$ has an area of $72$ and $\Delta ODC$ has an area of $288$. Find $x$ and $y$. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know:
$$16*(16+x)=18*(18+y)$$
And:
$$\frac{\frac12*18*16\sin\theta}{\frac12*(18+y)*(16+x)\sin\theta}=\frac{72}{288}=\frac14$$
So:
$$x=20,y=14$$